# PDF File Preview Not Working On Salesforce Mobile App - "Display alternative file previews" Doesn't Work

Tags: salesforce1-app, pdf, files, servicecloud, sales-cloud

I have a problem with PDF File previews which are attached to Account records in Salesforce.

When users enter on the Salesforce mobile app using an Android tablet and try to preview a PDF file, not all the contents inside the PDF show up. In the screenshot below, the cells appear to have no content

[image]

When the same file is previewed on a desktop computer in Salesforce, all the contents appear without a problem, the checkboxes appear as checked, and the numbers can be seen (96, 20, 80)

[image]

I tried to fix this by following the documentation and enabling the setting called "Display alternative file previews" (going to Setup > Salesforce Files > General Settings) but it isn't working either, so I'm trying to find another alternative fix.

This is the link to the doc. article
https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000382573&type=1

My Team is using Android version 12 on a Samsung Galaxy Tab A7. We tried uninstalling the app, installing the latest version, and clearing the cache on the device, but the problem still persists.

If anyone has a suggestion it would be greatly appreciated. Thank you all.